# What is Earl Horseriver's actual/original given name?

Tags: lois-mcmaster-bujold, chalion

In *The Hallowed Hunt*, Ingrey knows the current Earl Horseriver as Wencel, the slow and uninteresting cousin he knew as a boy having somehow grown up into a very much not-slow adult. Of course, it turns out that this is because

> it's not actually Wencel, just Wencel's body taken over by his father's soul. And of course, what everyone knew as Wencel's father was also not the person he was born as, because his body was taken over by *his* father's soul when said father died.

And so on down the line, back to the Horseriver who was Hallow King at the battle of Holytree/Bloodfield. It's clear that

> it's this original personality that's dominant - it had to quickly become so, because for example there was no time to prepare the third, um, recipient of the curse for any sort of sharing of power.

So what was that original Horseriver king's given name? Does Ingrey know it? It's doubtless written down in one of the books in the fabled Horseriver library, but is it known/taught, 400 years later? Does Horseriver himself know it?